# Find out the code that is doing the GET in a Backbone Marionette application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm new to Backbone/Marionette. I've started reading documentation which is helping. However, I need some help on this one.

I've been watching our app in Chrome Dev Tools and I see it's contacting a REST endpoint every 5 seconds.

I would like to know which code is actually doing that REST api call and also would like to know which view will be used for the data it received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Network tab, where your requests are listed, hover over a link in the **Initiator** column.

As a result you will see a popup with call stack for a selected request.

[image]

Comment: This will of course only work if you don't have concatenated/transpiled code. If you do, then make sure you enable source maps

Comment: That is amazing Artyom! I've never done that technique :D So happy to learn something new

Comment: Dan, I heard source maps the other day. I don't know how to turn it on. Is it ok to turn it on in a production site? It's because the other day, we had issues and everything was pointing to line 1

Comment: @devwannabe I am not sure about enabling source maps, but if you are dealing with minified assets, use Dev Tools beautifier: https://monosnap.com/file/eq82gtysrHYcRqpellaPRu5MRLG5JN.png